# Picking apart a string and replacing it

Tags: java, regex

I have been picking my brain lately and can't seem to figure out how to pull the "text" from this string and replace the found pattern with those word(s).

```
Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\{(.+?)\\}\\]"); 
Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(sb);
```

`sb` is the string that contains a few occurrences of these patterns that start with `[{` and end with `]}`.

```
[{ md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.searchtype, l : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.l, v : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.v}}, { md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.topicgroup, l : "Books", v : "ETBO"}}]
```

gets returned as

```
md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.searchtype, l : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.l, v : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.v}}, { md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.topicgroup, l : "Books", v : "ETBO"}
```

Notice the lack of `[{` and `}]`. I manage to find the above pattern but how would I find the words `set` and `Book` and then replace the original found pattern with only those words. I can search the string if it contains a `"` via

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.group(1).contains("\"");
```

but I really just need some ideas about how to go about doing this.

Comment: OK, I am very confused. Can you show a "before and after" version of your example string?

Comment: its actually fairly large.. but goes along the lines of "hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, [{ md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.searchtype, l : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.l, v : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.v}}, { md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.topicgroup, l : "Books", v : "ETBO"}}] , some more text here, and some more" -> the [{ }] parts should be replaced with the text inside of them in this case set, books, etbo... resulting in a final string of "hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, set set Books ETBO , some more text here, and some more"

Comment: Can you not just use string.replaceAll to remove all occurrences of "[{" and "}]"?

Comment: replaceAll isn't applicable because this data is dynamic since im pulling it from files and cleaning it before I intend to parse it. I am replacing the found pattern with some of the bits that are in inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (answer based on your first comment)?

> its actually fairly large.. but goes along the lines of "hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, [{ md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.searchtype, l : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.l, v : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.v}}, { md : {o : "set", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.topicgroup, l : "Books", v : "ETBO"}}] , some more text here, and some more" -> the [{ }] parts should be replaced with the text inside of them in this case set, books, etbo... resulting in a final string of "hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, set set Books ETBO , some more text here, and some more"

```
// text from your comment
String sb = "hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, [{ md : "
        + "{o : \"set\", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : "
        + "_LU.el.searchtype, l : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.l, "
        + "v : _LU[_LU.el.searchtype].nfts.v}}, { md : {o : "
        + "\"set\", et : _LU.et.v.v }, d : {t : _LU.el.topicgroup, "
        + "l : \"Books\", v : \"ETBO\"}}] , "
        + "some more text here, and some more";

Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\{(.+?)\\}\\]");
Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(sb);

// pattern that finds words between quotes
Pattern serchWordsInQuores = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");

// here I will collect words in quotes placed in [{ and }] and separate 
// them with one space
StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();

// buffer used while replacing [{ xxx }] part with words found in xxx
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find()) {// looking for [{ xxx }]
    words.delete(0, words.length());

    //now I search for words in quotes from [{ xxx }]
    Matcher m = serchWordsInQuores.matcher(matcher.group());
    while (m.find())
        words.append(m.group(1)).append(" ");

    matcher.appendReplacement(output, words.toString().trim());
    //trim was used to remove last space
}
//we also need to append last part of String that wasn't used in matcher
matcher.appendTail(output);

System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

> hello my name is, etc, etc, etc, set set Books ETBO , some more text here, and some more

Answer (score 1):

**LATEST REVISION**

An Example on how to loop over a string with multiple boundaries and replacing at each level

```
public static String replace(CharSequence rawText, String oldWord, String newWord, String regex) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = patt.matcher(rawText);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(rawText.length());
    while (m.find()) {

        String text = m.group(1);
        if(oldWord == null || oldWord.isEmpty()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(newWord));
        } else {
            if(text.matches(oldWord)) {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(newWord));
            }
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String rawText = "[{MY NAME IS \"NAME\"}]";
    rawText += " bla bla bla [{I LIVE IN \"SOME RANDOM CITY\" WHERE THE PIZZA IS GREAT!}]";
    rawText += " bla bla etc etc [{I LOVE \"A HOBBY\"}]";
    System.out.println(rawText);
    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\{(.+?)\\}\\]");
    Matcher matcherBoundary = searchPattern.matcher(rawText);

    List<String> replacement = new ArrayList<String>();
    replacement.add("BOB");
    replacement.add("LOS ANGELES");
    replacement.add("PUPPIES");
    int counter = 0;

    while (matcherBoundary.find()) {

        String result = Test.replace(matcherBoundary.group(1), null, replacement.get(counter), "\"([^\"]*)\"");
        System.out.println(result);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
**Raw Text**
[{MY NAME IS "NAME"}] bla bla bla [{I LIVE IN "SOME RANDOM CITY" WHERE THE PIZZA IS GREAT!}] bla bla etc etc [{I LOVE "A HOBBY"}]
**In Every Loop**
MY NAME IS BOB
I LIVE IN LOS ANGELES WHERE THE PIZZA IS GREAT!
I LOVE PUPPIES
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my understanding is that `sb` is not that string, but rather a larger string that includes multiple sections of that format (in `[{ }]`), so you have to find the individual `[{ }]` sections before getting the quotes out of them. Also, I don't see any indication that `\w+` is appropriate -- you need to match whatever is between the quotes, whether that's a word or multiple words or just gibberish.

Comment: would `(\"[^\"]*\")` be better than `(\\w+)` ?

Comment: I used `\"([^\"]*)\"` personally, since I don't think he wants to keep the quote marks, but yes.

Comment: I had it like that, but what if it has to be quoted?

Comment: Would prefer them unquoted but that isn't a big deal. And @KRyan that assumption is correct, sb is a very very large string and this is a substring of it. Also the parts inside `[{ }]`aren't known. All that can be guaranteed is that there are some words in quotes inside of the `[{ }]`

Comment: @wazy: and how does my answer handle your input?

Comment: @Wazy give me 5 and I will merge your regex with mine

Comment: @wazy look at my new revision

Comment: I guess I am doing a replacement of quotes and leaving everything else the same within the boundaries... while @Pshemo is replacing everything with just the quoted  part

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think you need to do this in three passes, first time matching the section between the `[{ }]`, and the second time going through the match doing the replace, and the third time replacing that match with the string you got from the second pass.

You already have a pattern for the first match, and you'd just use it again for the third match, when you replace it with the result of the second pass.

For the second pass, you're going to need to `replaceAll` on the first match. Something like this:

```
Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\{(.+?)\\}\\]"); 
Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(sb);
while ( matcher.find() )
{
    matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\"", "$1"));
}
```

The first pass is done by `matcher.find()`. The next one is done by `matcher.group().replaceAll()`, which is then passed into `matcher.replaceFirst()` for the third pass. The third pass is a little weird: it replaces the first example of the `[{ }]`. However, since we're starting from the beginning and moving forward, that will be the one we just found, and we won't match it again because it will get replaced by a non-matching string. The docs recommend resetting the matcher after `replaceFirst()`, but I *think* it will be safe here because it will continue from after that replacement, which is exactly what we want.

I would point out that this is *not* particularly efficient. I think that you would be better off doing more of this manually rather than with regular expressions.

Comment: this seems to be stuck indefinitely on the while loop

Comment: @wazy: could you try adding `matcher.reset();` after the `replaceFirst()` line (inside the loop)?